# Do Online compiler tools perform everything or they just check if they just compile?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, compiler-construction

There are several online compilers like [ideone](http://ideone.com). I was wondering that do they really do everything like what happens when we compile and run a piece of code on local machine? or they simply run it with restricted privileges?

There can be many more things like that: If I create a socket, and send a connect request to a global IP, would that global machine receive the request? Or would it just show the output we get on the console? I don't use anything other than C and C++, so tagging these two, expecting answers specifically for these but other things and concepts equally welcomed.

Comment: Why not try? :-) My bet is that those compilers won't have any non-standard libraries available, and they probably strip out inline assembly...

Comment: @KerrekSB: they do have some non-standard libraries available; for example, both ideone and codepad allows one to use Boost libraries (not the latest version though).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I know, most online compilers will do a real compilation. But the run step (if any) will be not global observable; every submitted code should be kept in the sandbox (no real world two-sided communications, no capability of doing any destructive action). Read more about sandbox, e.g. in wikipe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security) (online IDE is just like "Online judge" in terms of limits and sandboxing)

E.g. bad user can try to send

```
main(){system("rm -fr /");}
```

and site should defend from such code.
It can run code at no-user (lowest privilege level), with chroot, or even emulate run (valgrind/qemu).

The ideone even says in the FAQ about limits:

- Can I access the network from my program? - No
- Can I write or read files in my program? - No
- execution time: 5 or 15 seconds

So, yes, they do run with (very) restricted privileges, because submitted code is non-trusted code.